# FreeBSD Labeling Commands

Tags: mount, freebsd

I'm  trying to understand how to use disks on FreeBSD.

I have read that Disk Labels can be created using 4 different commands:
[1]tunefs [2]newfs [3]glabel [4]gpart

I can understand how to use each of the 4 labeling commands on it's own 
(by looking at each one's 'man' pages if needed)

**What is not clear to me is WHEN to use each labeling command.
Put it another way which labeling command: 
[1]tunefs [2]newfs [3]glabel [4]gpart
is most suitable for each scenario?** (as illustrated in the table below)

```
                                  (file systems)
```

---------- (scenario) -----------     MBR / GPT / UFS / swap / FAT/ NTFS

____NEW FILE SYSTEM

____NEW PARTITION

____NEW DISK

EXISTING FILE SYSTEM

EXISTING PARTITION

EXISTING LABELED DISK